# Prune does not ignore top level directory of what I specified

Tags: find

When I do this

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
mkdir -p a/d/e
find ./a -path ./a/d -prune -o -type d
```

I get this:

```
./a
./a/d
./a/b
./a/b/c
```

I must be using the prune flag wrong. How do I ignore the directory `./a/d` as well from the output of my find?

Answer (score 0):

`-prune` succeds on `./a/d` so that branch succeds and prints,
 `-type d` also finds it in in `./a`

So, I think you want `-false` after `-prune`  and `-not -path ./a/d` after `-o`.

```
find ./a  -path ./a/d -prune -false -o -not -path ./a/d -type d
```